# How to allow to create a directory in home folder another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two users:

```
adduser user1
adduser user2
```

I need to allow creating folders in user2 home directory by user1

```
user2@ubuntu: mkdir /home/user1/tmp
```

How can I do that? Bacause now I get the error message:

```
mkdir "/home/user1/tmp" failed: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the primary purposes of group permissions in *nix. Create a group and make sure both users are members of that group, that the home directories have that group set as the group-owner, and that the permissions on the home directories include group-write. Something along these lines:

```
groupadd somegroupname
usermod -A somegroupname user1
usermod -A somegroupname user2
chgrp somegroupname ~user1/. ~user2/.
chmod g+rwx ~user1/. ~user2/.
```

Comment: On my Debian, instead of
`usermod -A somegroupname user1`
it should be
`usermod -a -G somegroupname user1`

Comment: @Bonswouar Good point - there may be different versions of certain utilities on different distributions. When in doubt, always check your  specific documentation / manual pages / etc....

Answer (score -1):

In order for sudo to work you must give the user sudo permission int the sudoers file. That file can be found in /etc/. Otherwise changes can only be done by ~root.

{username}   ALL=(ALL)     ALL

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: If you do that the user can run anything as root, which would be bad. Also if they create a folder in the users home directory the created folder would be owned by root